# 2D array of 0's ruining logic of unrelated loop - C++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, binary

The listed code is from a larger project that I am working on (I deleted almost everything else that wasn't necessary for this posting) that is having some trouble running properly. I found the line that is causing the error but I'm hoping for an explanation as to why this line is causing it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tgmath.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  const int m = 2;    //  Number of rows
  const int n = 2;    //  Number of cols

  int totalPoss = 0;  //  Number of unique possibile m X n binary matrices

  //  2^(m * n) = the number of unique binary
  //  combinations of m X n matrices
  int stop = pow(2, m * n);

  //  Error when a = 0, 1 | m = 0 | n = 1
  for (int a = 0; a < stop; a++) {
    int poss[m][n] = {0};       //  2D Array to store each possible matrix
    int nextGen[m][n] = {0};    //  2D Array to store the next generation of cells
    int rem[m * n];             //  1D Array to store the binary entries of the poss[m][n]

    totalPoss = a;
    int hold = a;           //  Stores the current "possibility number" (i.e when
                            //  a = hold = 1 the binary equivilent of 1 will be stored
                            //  in rem[m * n])

    //  Generate binary number based on whatever a is at current iteration
    int c = 0;
    while (hold > 0) {

      // storing remainder in binary array
      rem[c] = hold % 2;
      hold = hold / 2;
      c++;
    }

    cout << "Binary: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < (m * n); i++) {
      cout << rem[i] << " ";
    }

    cout << endl << endl;
  }

  cout << "Total possibilities: " << totalPoss+1 << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

The line in question is line 19, or `int nextGen[m][n] = {0};`. The program's purpose in this state is to output all possible unique binary numbers of 4 bits. The number to translate to binary is determined by the initial `for` loop. The number is translated in the `while` loop and stored in `rem[m][n]`. This code works fine unless you include line 19. For whatever reason when this 2D array is created the output for 0 and 1 is 1 14 0 0 but outputs correctly for 2-15. My question is why this one (seemingly) unrelated line breaks my code.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rem` is not completely initialized. The loop that assigns values only iterates until `hold` is zero, so it does not set the higher elements. But the loop that prints it always prints `n * m` elements.

The effect of defining `nextGen` is incidental. It may affect where `rem` is placed in memory, resulting in it happening to contain zeroes rather than other bits (and likely you are compiling without optimization).

Initialize `rem` to all zeroes or change the loop that sets its elements.

Comment: Interesting, I initialized ```rem``` to 0 and it worked fine, thank you!! Would you have any idea why it always output 1 14 0 0?